# jQuery - load remote html form in modal window and submit it on same modal window

Tags: jquery, window, modal-dialog

I need to load html page that contains form in modal window. When the modal window is opened and submit button is pressed I need to submit the data in the same remote html page and then the modal window to be closed. Here is my code:
**I'm opening the modal window with this code (page.html):**

```
    $(".genbutton-options, .ajax-edit").click(function(){                                                                                                                                                                
    var id = $(this).attr("id").replace('edit-', '');                                                                                                                                                                
    var xtraParam = "";                                                                                                                                                                                              
    if( $(this).attr("rel") == "profile" ){                                                                                                                                                                          
        var xtraParam = "&r=sm";                                                                                                                                                                                     
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    if( $(this).attr("rel") == "set" ){                                                                                                                                                                              
        var xtraParam = "&r=s";                                                                                                                                                                                      
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    if( $(this).attr("rel") == "stream" ){                                                                                                                                                                           
        var xtraParam = "&r=stream";                                                                                                                                                                                 
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    var dialogOpts = {                                                                                                                                                                                               
        modal: true,                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        bgiframe: true,                                                                                                                                                                                              
        autoOpen: false,                                                                                                                                                                                             
        width: 716,                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        buttons: {                                                                                                                                                                                                   
            "Save": function() {                                                                                                                                                                                     
                $("#content-dialog").hide();                                                                                                                                                                         
                $(this).append("<div class=\"preloader-ajax\">Hold on...</div>");                                                                                                                                    
                $(".ui-button").addClass("ui-state-disabled");                                                                                                                                                       
                $("form[name='edit-ajax-form']").submit();                                                                                                                                                           
            },                                                                                                                                                                                                       
            "Cancel": function() {$(this).dialog("close");}                                                                                                                                                          
        },                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        open: function() {                                                                                                                                                                                           
            $("#ed-"+id+"").load("edit.php?media="+id+""+xtraParam+"");                                                                                                                                    
            $("#edit-loader-"+id+"").show();                                                                                                                                                                         
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    };                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    $("#ed-"+id+"").dialog(dialogOpts);                                                                                                                                                                              
    $("#ed-"+id+"").dialog("open");                                                                                                                                                                                  
    return false;                                                                                                                                                                                                    
});
```

**Here is the page that is opened in modal window (edit.php):**

```
    <div id="content-dialog">
    <form action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <div class="dialog-td1">Title</div>
    <div class="dialog-td2">
        <input type="text" name="title" value="Suitcase Chair?" class="dialog-inputtext" id="inputPicTitle" />
        <p class="dialog-help" style="visibility:hidden">Some cool, sexy or funny title is required. Min 3 chars.</p>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="save" id="buttonSignup" class="dialog-button right" value="Save" />
    <div class="preloader-signup right">Hold On</div>
    <a href="javascript:history.back(1)" class="dialog-button-grey right" id="buttonCancel">Cancel</a>
    </form>
</div>
<?php
if(isset($_POST)){
   //do something
   echo "data submitted";
}
```

?>

The problem is that when I click on submit button, data is saved but browser get redirected to edit.php (the same page that was opened in modal window). Wat I want to do is, when I hit submit button, data to be saved and then modal window to be closed without any browser redirection or refreshes. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried using ajax to submit the data then close the modal?

Comment: You mean to submit via ajax in edit.php? Or to use ajax in page.html?

Answer (score 2):

You have to change your code a bit:

```
 $("form[name='edit-ajax-form']").submit();
```

to:

```
      $.ajax(
        {type:'POST', 
         url: $("form[name='edit-ajax-form']").attr('action'),
         data:$("form[name='edit-ajax-form']").serialize(),
         success: function(response) {
               alert(response);
         })
      });
```

This does sent your request as ajax and gets the response. You could handle it a bit more. And only close the modal window if the response was successfull.

Edit:

something like that:

```
"Save": function() {


            $("#content-dialog").hide();                                                                                                                                                                         
            var preloader = $(this).append("<div class=\"preloader-ajax\">Hold on...</div>");  
            $(".ui-button").addClass("ui-state-disabled");  
            var dialog = $(this);
            $.ajax(
                    {type:'POST', 
                     url: $("form[name='edit-ajax-form']").attr('action'),
                     data:$("form[name='edit-ajax-form']").serialize(),
                     success: function(response) {
                           $(preloader).remove();
                            dialog.close();
                     },
                    error: function() {
                        $(preloader).remove();
                        alert('something bad happend pls fill out again');
                        $(".ui-button").addClass("ui-state-enabled");  
                    }
                  });                                                                                                                                  


        },
```

Comment: What if response is not success? How can I keep modal window opened if there is some error?

Comment: i edited the code which you may directly use. but its heavily untested.

Comment: I have applied your modifications but even if error occurred, modal window is still closed after the form is submitted.

Comment: try opening a new question, because your initial questions is solved as far as i understand it. and if i post now answers based on new questions from this comment, this could be very confusing for other readers.